# Access own class properties during creation

Tags: c#

When initially creating a new class record, how can you access its own properties?

Below is my example structure which I am wanting to set `Total` as the sum of `No1` and `No2`

```
    class ROWDATA
    {
        public int No1;
        public int No2;
        public int Total;
    }

    ROWDATA RowData = new ROWDATA
    {
        No1 = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("fuel_tank_no_1")),
        No2 = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("fuel_tank_no_2")),
        Total = No1 + No2 // this does not work
     };
```

I get an error stating that `The name 'No1' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Give more details about `Total`, `No1` and `No2` objects.

Comment: Can you show the code for the Total property?

Comment: Updated with more info. Additionally, I call them properties but I may be incorrect.

Comment: @GrantWinney - Legend! Can you put this as an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update the `Total` property like this:

```
public int Total { get { return No1 + No2; } }
```

You can use this also:

```
var RowDataNo1 = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("fuel_tank_no_1"));
var RowDataNo2 = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("fuel_tank_no_2"));

ROWDATA RowData = new ROWDATA 
{
   No1 = RowDataNo1,
   No2 = RowDataNo2,
   Total = RowDataNo1 + RowDataNo2
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using [object initialiser syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) and in there you do not have access to `read` properties. You can either use the two values you've already read or change the property.

**Using the values**

```
ROWDATA RowData = new ROWDATA
{
    No1 = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("fuel_tank_no_1")),
    No2 = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("fuel_tank_no_2")),
    Total = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("fuel_tank_no_1")) + 
            reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("fuel_tank_no_2"))
 };
```

In this case it would probably be preferable to store the values in variables and use them rather than repeated access to the `reader` object.

**Change Total Property**

The preferred option is to change your `Total` property to something like this:

```
public int Total
{
    get { return No1 + No2; }
}
```

Comment: Hrm.. Yeah I figured this might be the only way to do it. I should probably use real properties and have a getter for Total that does the math in a function. I was hoping for a quick and dirty way. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DavidG Do you have an MSDN link or similar source for your first statement? Not that I doubt you (and of course it's easily tested) but that I might need the link to support my similar assertion at some point.

Comment: @ClickRick Unfortunatly I cannot find anything on MSDN that states this explicitly.

Comment: Link found and added as another answer.

Answer (score 3):

As [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23969609/3419534) by [DavidG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1663001/davidg), you do not have access to `get` property accessors when using object initialiser syntax.

[The C# specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx#csharp3.0overview_topic12)<sup>1</sup> specifically states

> It is not possible for an object or collection initializer to refer to the object instance being initialized.

---

<sup>1</sup> Specifically, C# 3.0 spec, section 26.4 Object and Collection Initializers